# How to compress this if else statement

Tags: python

```
if word not in word_map.keys():
    set1 = set()
    set1.add(line_no)                
    word_map[word] = set1
else:
    set1 = set()
    set1.add(line_no)
    set1.update(word_map[word])
    word_map[word] = set1
```

Is there anyway I can compress this into not needing an if? I have to check if the key exists so I know if I need to add what is already in set key or not, if I just have

```
set1.update(word_map[word])
```

And the key does not exist, it will error out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can compress it by removing duplicate code like this:

```
set1 = set()
set1.add(line_no)
if word in word_map.keys():
    set1.update(word_map[word])
word_map[word] = set1
```

Then you should think about what [`set.update`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.update) does. It basically adds all the elements from one set into the current one. So you can reorder your code like this too:

```
if word in word_map.keys():
    set1 = word_map[word]
else:
    set1 = set()
set1.add(line_no)
word_map[word] = set1
```

We can then make this simpler by using [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to remove the if completely:

```
set1 = word_map.get(word, set())
set1.add(line_no)
word_map[word] = set1
```

And then, we can also use [`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) instead to make sure that we have a set, and just add to that directly:

```
set1 = word_map.setdefault(word, set())
set1.add(line_no)
```

As we now use the set that’s inside the dictionary, we don’t need to write back its value to the dictionary (we have a reference). And we could even make it a single line then:

```
word_map.setdefault(word, set()).add(line_no)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
set1 = set()
set1.add(line_no)                
if word in word_map.keys():
    set1.update(word_map[word])
word_map[word] = set1
```

Although, on the assumption that `word_map` is a `dict`, the `if` should be written like this:

```
if word in word_map:
```

Comment: Yep, thanks, can't believe i didn't see that ..  Yes it is a dict.